# Extract column without replacing the original one

Tags: r, regex, extract

I want to extract some values out of a column with the help of regex. I am trying it with the following code:

```
df <- extract(df, Präfixkosten_2, into = c('Präfixkosten_2_1','Präfixkosten_2_2'), '(MBC-[^\\s]+) (.*)')
```

It works well. Präfixkosten_2 is splitted in Präfixkosten_2_1 and Präfixkosten_2_2. But the original column Präfixkosten_2 is going to be deleted/replaced by the two new columns.

Is there a way to do it without replacing the original column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `remove=FALSE`:

```
extract(..., remove = FALSE)
```